# How to convert bytes to long in java

Tags: java, arrays, endianness

Here i have one String and i converted this string to long and than this long value converted into bytes. This byte array length is 6.

```
    final byte[] tagBytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(8).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN)
            .putLong(Long.parseLong("02201156116")).array();
    System.arraycopy(tagBytes, 0, tag, 0, 6);
    Log.d("TAG", "TAG in bytes "+Arrays.toString(tag));
```

Here i got output like this `[52, 84, 49, -125, 0, 0]`

Now i want to convert this output bytes in String as like before `"02201156116"`

So here i have to first order bytes in BIG_ENDIAN first and then wrap Bytes and get long value from it. 
But Here i am Surprised why it is not work for

```
ByteBuffer.wrap(tempDateBytes).order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN).getLong()
```

this and its work for

`ByteBuffer.wrap(tempDateBytes).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).getLong()` this, By d way we have to Apply BIG_ENDIAN becuase when we convert long to bytes we used LITTLE_ENDIAN. So i think we have to use here BIG_ENDIAN. but its not works for BIG_ENDIAN, its works for LITTLE_ENDIAN.

This code i used to convert `[52, 84, 49, -125, 0, 0]` to `02201156116`

```
    long time,time1;
    final byte[] tempDateBytes = new byte[8];
    System.arraycopy(tagBytes, 0, tempDateBytes, 0, 6);
    time1 = ByteBuffer.wrap(tempDateBytes).order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN).getLong();
    time = ByteBuffer.wrap(tempDateBytes).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN).getLong();
    Log.d("TAG", "Orignal TAG "+time);
    Log.d("TAG", "BAD TAG  "+time1);
```

Comment: Am I reading the question correct? Haven't you already solved your problem?

Comment: Won't `ByteBuffer.getLong` throw an exception if you only give it 6 bytes (as a `long` is eight bytes)?

Comment: @IanRoberts:The `byte[]` has the size 8. He's only copying 6 bytes into it, but that doesn't matter.

Comment: What do you mean with "it doesn't work"? Any sequence of up to 8 bytes can be made into a long, as "8 bytes" and "long" are essentially the same thing.

Comment: @Ingo Here i knw i solved this problem, But i want to know when i convert long to byte at that time i used little endian but while i am converting bytes to long at that time i have to use big endian , but i used big endian and its not work . Its work only with little endian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about it in terms of  `short`. Let's say we encode the value 258:

```
258 = 256 + 2 = 0x0102
```

Now, if we put this in an array, we must decide which byte we put at index 0. We can do

```
{ 0x01, 0x02 }
```

or

```
{ 0x02, 0x01 }
```

No order is per se better than the other, but the crucial point is to remember which order we used, when we ever want do decode the array and want to get the value 258 back.

This is the purpose of LITTLE_ENDIAN and BIG_ENDIAN. On encoding, it tells the byte order to use. On decoding, it tells the byte order we used when we encoded.

Hence, to not mess things up, be sure to use the *same* byte order on encoding and decoding.

Comment: Ya i got your answer and Thanks to give this answer.

Comment: Here encoding means ByteBuffer.allocate() and decoding means ByteBuffer.wrap() ? Am i right?

Comment: @Sam_k - encoding = putLong, decoding = getLong.

Comment: So Your This line is my main answer :  `This is the purpose of LITTLE_ENDIAN and BIG_ENDIAN. On encoding, it tells the byte order to use. On decoding, it tells the byte order we used when we encoded.`